# Was this question migrated from Not an answer flagging? Shouldn't that be linked to the original question context?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, not-an-answer, moderator-tools

Take a look at that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/30800845/1064325

Note a few points about it:

- The `0 down vote` part: it says it was a copy-paste.
- The `I have a similar problem ad in the question.` seems like a comment to a question.
- The OP has only 1 reputation, so he/she can't comment. It feels like it was an answer.
- The question appear to be out of context due to the lack of the question it was referring.

***Probably***, someone flagged it as Not an answer, and some moderator handled it by copying that answer and posting it exactly as is as a question.

1) Are those assumptions correct? (Or, at least, do moderators handle NAA flags manually?)

If so:

1.1) Please, could you always add a link to the question it was referring to?

1.2) Couldn't the moderator tools make the copy-paste and the linking automatically?

Comment: Mods can't create questions for users.  The user was probably told to ask, then screwed up their copypasta and didn't fix it because they're slightly doltish.  No mystery here.

Comment: @Will Hmm, I think I was wrong then :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.

The user posted the question as an answer to a different question and then, when informed that it was the wrong thing to do, copied and pasted the output rather than retyping the question or copying the input.

Moderators cannot create a question on someone's behalf.

What's depressing is that someone suggested an edit that didn't remove the "9 down vote" and someone approved it (though the OP did too)

Comment: Yeah, that's really awful. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I somewhat thought that NAAs had some further handling than just being deleted.

Comment: @falsarella - not really. We can convert them to comments on the question or other answers, but that's it.

Comment: Great. Converting NAA into comments often makes sense.